# Dataweave : Days passed and days left in current month

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am able to get the days passed in current month. But don't know how to get days left in current month.

For example in this month (June) days passed=7 and days left = 23

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "daysPassed" : now().day -1,
    "daysLeft" : ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataWeave doesn't seem to have a built-in function to compute the end of month, so I calculate it using some date arithmetic.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun daysLeftOnMonth(d) = do {
    var nextMonthDate = d as Date + |P1M|
    var endOfMonth= ( nextMonthDate  - ( ("P$(nextMonthDate.day as String)D" as Period) )).day
    ---
    endOfMonth - d.day + 1 
}
---
{
    "daysPassed" : now().day - 1,
    "daysLeft" : daysLeftOnMonth(now())
}
```

To explain more in detail, first I add a month to the current date:

```
var nextMonthDate = d as Date + |P1M|
```

Then I go to the the beginning of the month, less one day, so I get the last day of the current month:

```
nextMonthDate  - (("P$(nextMonthDate.day as String)D" as Period)
```

The trick was how to rest a dynamic time period in DataWeave. I had to search for it. You have to construct the period as a string, then coerce it into a period.

Then I just substract the days passed to the number of day of the last day of the month.

Comment: This works really well, even for feb leap year. If you don't mind could you explain the two lines. I cant seem to wrap my head around it. what is |P1M| ?

var nextMonthDate = d as Date + |P1M|
    var endOfMonth= ( nextMonthDate  - ( ("P$(nextMonthDate.day as String)D" as Period) )).day

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to this and you can always build the leap year check into this.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var thirtyDayMonths = [4,6,8,10]
---
{
    "daysPassed" : now().day -1,
    "daysLeft" : if (thirtyDayMonths contains now().month) 
                         (30-now().day) 
                 else if (now().month == 2) 
                         (28-now().month) 
                 else (31-now().month)
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to leave leap years out of the equation.

Comment: Like i said, it can always be built out.. I never mentioned to keep it out of the scope of the solution.